# How to replace value in json object to string using Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a json object as below in Azure Dashboard:

{...,'Signal':'0.0',...}

where the Signal can take on the values of 0.0 for No and 1.0 for Yes. I wish to convert these values to "yes" and "no" using Kusto. I tried to do the following but it doesn't work:

| extend signal = tostring(replace(@"0.0",@"No",object['Signal']))

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to recreate the dynamic value with the value of `Signal` replaced with `"yes"`/`"no"`**

You should extract the value of `Signal`, translate it to `"yes"`/`"no"` depending on the value, and then construct a new dynamic value, which contains the translated signal, and the rest of the properties in the original dynamic value, like this:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[
    dynamic({'Signal':'0.0','AnotherSignal':'0.0'}),
    dynamic({'Signal':'1.0','AnotherSignal':'0.0'})
]
| project bag_merge(pack("Signal", iff(d.Signal == 0.0, "No", "Yes")), d)
```

Output:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| { "Signal": "No", "AnotherSignal": "0.0" } |
| { "Signal": "Yes", "AnotherSignal": "0.0" } |

**If you want to extract the value of `Signal`, and replace it with `"yes"`/`"no"`**

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[
    dynamic({'Signal':'0.0','AnotherSignal':'0.0'}),
    dynamic({'Signal':'1.0','AnotherSignal':'0.0'})
]
| extend UpdatedSignal = iff(d.Signal == 0.0, "No", "Yes")
```

| d | UpdatedSignal |
| --- | --- |
| { "Signal": "0.0", "AnotherSignal": "0.0" } | No |
| { "Signal": "1.0", "AnotherSignal": "0.0" } | Yes |

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[dynamic({'Signal':'0.0'})]
| extend Signal = replace('0.0', 'Yes',tostring(d.Signal))
```